# Faster blob storage copy tools across regions

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I need to copy containers in Blob Storage across regions and wanted a solution that would do it without having to download locally and then upload it again. For example, I am trying to copy a container from East US to a container in SouthEast Asia. I used AzCopy to do that and the throughput I got was 22 Mb/s at best. I am not doing /SyncCopy either so is this best throughput the tool provides cross region ? Do we any other external tools that provide faster results ? Thanks.

Comment: did you try AzCopy cmdlet?

Comment: hey yes i did try AzCopy. I wanted to check if there is something faster than that.

Answer (score 2):

Azcopy is your best bet when it comes to rapid data move within Azure. You could also consider using Azure Import/Export service if you have an urgent timeline for large amount of data transfer:

> using Azure Import/Export service to securely transfer large amounts of data to Azure Blob storage and Azure Files by shipping disk drives to an Azure data center. This service can also be used to transfer data from Azure storage to hard disk drives and ship to your on-premise sites. Data from a single internal SATA disk drive can be imported either to Azure Blob storage or Azure Files.

There are also some external tools: 
https://www.signiant.com/signiant-flight-for-fast-large-file-transfers-to-azure-blob-storage/
and:
http://asperasoft.com/fast-file-transfer-with-aspera-sod-azure/

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-service**
**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-moving-data**

Comment: thanks a lot Adam for the reply. I was not aware of the Import/Export though I'll keep it as my last option. I'll research the other tools you mentioned.